# Dropbox Explorer token works with/v2/move but not in when using token generated Dropbox app console

Tags: dropbox-api, bearer-token

When I use Dropbox's API Explorer and get a token, the request works to change a file's name.  It even works with that token in Postman.

When I go to the app console and get an access token, the request will not work with the given token using the same code with Explorer while only changing the bearer token.  I get a from_lookup/not_found error, see json below.  The only difference in the Postman request is the bearer token (and the values of the to and from path's which I am flipping back and forth for testing).

Am I doing something wrong?  I can use the token generated in the Explorer but how long will that last?  I need this to be long-lasting.

{
"error_summary": "from_lookup/not_found/",
"error": {
".tag": "from_lookup",
"from_lookup": {
".tag": "not_found"
}
}
}

Comment: I even tried the access token generated within the API documentation sample code for move_v2 where you can click, if you are signed in, and get a bearer token.  The only token that works seems to be what is generated in Explorer.  I am not getting a not authenticated error but a not found error which is odd because I'm using the same paths for all calls. It works with explorer which would indicate the path is good.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API offers [a few different levels of access](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions) to a connected account. The Dropbox API Explorer uses "Full Dropbox" access, meaning it can access anything in the connected account.

It sounds like you may have registered your own app with "App folder" access though, meaning that it can only access the contents of the special app folder that gets created for it (by default at "/Apps/" for accounts with the English locale).

So, any paths you supply when using an access token for an app folder app will automatically be interpreted relative to the app folder (not the Dropbox root, like when using a full Dropbox app like the API Explorer). That is likely why you are getting this error, i.e., because there is nothing at that path inside the app folder.

If you do need to access the contents of the account outside the app folder, you'll need to [register](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create) an app with "Full Dropbox" access instead and use an access token for that.

Also, for reference, the access tokens returned by the Dropbox API Explorer are only meant for trying out the API, and shouldn't be used in your real app. Also, they are short-lived access tokens and expire after four hours. (You can tell when a Dropbox API access token is short-lived by the "sl." prefix.)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew about the files needing to be in a special folder for this particular app but didn't know the path was relative to that folder rather than the root directory.  When I removed the first part of the path (from the root directory) it worked great!